# How to show only child terms of a taxonomy on a table

Tags: taxonomy-terms, forms

I want to display only child terms of a taxonomy on a tableselect ?
Example :

Term A has : terms {B,C,D}
term E has : term {F}

I want to display only {B,C,D,F} on a table (in order to make some stuff with checkbox etc)

Comment: Explain more , like I'm creating a view of node "A" , it contains a taxonomy term , The vocabulary has .......

Comment: Yep i just add explication on my question

Comment: I think you should try something in js

Comment: There is only weight on table taxonomy_term, I can't list only parents : example term with weight 0 is a parent, but he has a child, this child is -as his parent- with 0 on the weight

Comment: That's why weight field (on the table taxonomy_term) is not enough to make difference between the parent and his child

Answer (score 0):

Solved by joining two tables : taxonomy_term_data and taxonomy_term_hierarchy, the second one contains the field : parent ( 0 for parents, tid of the parent if it's a child term)